# Distribution where $(1/x)\%$ of observations are greater than $x$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request

I'm looking for a distribution with the domain $x \in (1, \infty)$ such that $P(X > x) = 1/x$. Therefore observations greater than $2$ occur $50\%$ of the time, observations greater than $10$ occur $10\%$ of the time, observations greater than $1.25$ occur $80\%$ of the time, etc.

It seems like the expected value and variance of this distribution would both be $\infty$, but I was wondering if there was a specific name for this distribution, or any other unique properties that are not immediately apparent.

Also if there are any papers or resources related to such a distribution those would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: Not 'distribution-theory'. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a function $f(x)$ such that $$\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt = \frac{1}{x}$$

Hint: Try differentating both sides.

> Differentiating both sides, I get $$ - f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} \to f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$$
>  It is easy to see that this satisfies $$\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt = \frac{1}{x}$$

In general, if you want $$\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt = g(x)$$ to be satisfied, you can differentiate both sides to get $$-f(x)=g'(x) \to f(x) = -g'(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative distribution function of your distribution is $1-\frac 1x$.  It duly goes from $0$ at $x=1$ and has limit $1$ as $x \to \infty$.  You can get the probability density function by taking the derivative, getting
$$f(x)=x^{-2}$$

The expected value is $\int_1^\infty xf(x)dx$, which diverges as $\log x$.  The variance will diverge even worse.